# String Evaluation not working

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have the following array in a shell script:

```
#! usr/bin/bash

schemaPrefix=("aos")
tables_aos=("A" "B" "C")
colnames_aos=("id" "id" "id")

for j in "${!schemaPrefix[@]}"; do

aschema=${schemaPrefix[j]}
schema=$aschema
eval tables=tables_$aschema
echo ${tables[@]}
done
```

This code should display:

```
A B C
```

However, it displays:

```
tables_aos
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: @steeldriver sorry.  This is a Linux type environment on Macbook Pro.  It should be Done, not End.  I have provided the full code now.

Comment: OK I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do here, but perhaps you want a *nameref* ex. `declare -n tables=tables_$aschema` in place of `eval tables=tables_$aschema`. However if the "Linux type environment" is not Ubuntu, you should ask elsewhere.

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for your help.  I have several lists.  They are named as "table" followed by underscore and a suffix.  For example, table_aos, table_apd, etc.  I want to loop through all those lists and print the content of each list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash version > 4.3, you can declare the `tables` variable as a *nameref*:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

schemaPrefix=("aos")
tables_aos=("A" "B" "C")

declare -n tables

for j in "${!schemaPrefix[@]}"; do
  aschema=${schemaPrefix[j]}
  tables=tables_$aschema
  echo "${tables[@]}"
done
```

The loop could be written more simply without indirection as

```
for aschema in "${schemaPrefix[@]}"; do
  tables=tables_$aschema
  echo "${tables[@]}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you.  But it only prints the name of the table: tables_aos.  It needs to print the contents of the table: A B C.  

I get this error message due to "declare":
declare: -n: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]

Comment: @DS89 are you actually using bash version > 4.3? Check with `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` and/or `bash --version`. Are you even using Ubuntu?

Comment: It is GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin21)
So, that could be the issue why declare is not working as expected.  Thanks for pointing that out.